# Internal Server error during install

Tags: error, server, installation

I've done a few installs of Craft and never had a problem. I'm currently trying to do an install on a new server under a subdmomain and getting the following results…

This results in 404
http://staging.example.com/admin

Using /index.php/admin or /index.php?p=admin results in Internal Server Error 500.

Comment: Nevermind. It was a permissions problem.

Answer (score 2):

In case it helps someone, my issue was the permissions for the root index.php file...It was 666 (writeable by group) and when I switched that file permissions to 644, the installation was able to move forward.